# React: TypeError: this.props.update is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Let me begin by saying that I'm very new to programming as a whole so please bare with me if i ask stupid questions.

Basically, I'm trying to add a date picker to a search application in react, I have the UI there, and I can pre-set a date range in the code. However I want the user to be able to select a start and end date for the search results.

I know my code is incomplete and I know where I am going wrong, but I just don't know how to 'fix' it.

Datepicker:

```
import React from "react";
import "date-fns";

import { Paper } from "@material-ui/core";

import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

class DatePickerWidget extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Paper id="date-picker-widget" elevation={8}>
        <Paper id="date-filters" elevation={8}>
          <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              margin="normal"
              id="date-picker-dialog"
              label="Start Date"
              format="yyyy/MM/dd"
              value={this.props.startDate}
              maxDate={this.props.endDate}
              onChange={(date) => this.props.update({ startDate: date })}
              KeyboardButtonProps={{
                "aria-label": "change start date",
              }}
            />
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              margin="normal"
              id="date-picker-dialog"
              label="End Date"
              format="yyyy/MM/dd"
              value={this.props.endDate}
              minDate={this.props.startDate}
              onChange={(date) => this.props.update({ endDate: date })}
              KeyboardButtonProps={{
                "aria-label": "change end date",
              }}
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        </Paper>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

export default DatePickerWidget;
```

Search box where the date picker is displayed:

```
    import React from "react";

import { TextField, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

import "./SearchBox.css"
import DatePickerWidget from "./DatePickerWidget"

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { searchTerm: "", results: "" };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.validateSearch = this.validateSearch.bind(this);
    this.clear = this.clear.bind(this);

  
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: this.props.searchTerm });
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.searchTerm !== this.props.searchTerm)
      this.setState({ searchTerm: this.props.searchTerm });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.update({ searchTerm: this.state.searchTerm });
    this.setState({ results: this.state.searchTerm });
  }

  validateSearch() {
    return this.state.searchTerm !== "";
  }

  clear() {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: "", results: "" });
    this.props.update({ searchTerm: "" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form id="search-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Button
            style={{ width: "40%" }}
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary"
            onClick={this.clear}
            disabled={this.state.results === ""}
          >
            Clear
          </Button>
          <TextField
            style={{ flexBasis: "100%" }}
            variant="outlined"
            label="Search Term"
            type="search"
            name="searchTerm"
            value={this.state.searchTerm}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <Button
            style={{ width: "40%" }}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            disabled={!this.validateSearch()}
            type="submit"
          >
            Search
          </Button>


          <DatePickerWidget startDate="2020/09/01" endDate="2020/09/30"/>
        </form>

        
        {this.state.results && (
          <Typography align="center" variant="body1">
            Displaying results for: {this.state.results}
          </Typography>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}


export default SearchBox;
```

The error I'm getting when I change the dates on the interface:

**TypeError: this.props.update is not a function**

```
          format="yyyy/MM/dd"
          value={this.props.startDate}
          maxDate={this.props.endDate}
        > onChange={(date) => this.props.update({ startDate: date })}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change start date",
```

I'm fairly certain the code is fine, I'm just not adding something to the searchbox which enables the user to update the date range.

I should also mention that I know this won't make any difference to what the search results return yet. Getting that functionality working is my next challenge.

Thanks in advance!

*Edit: I forgot to mention that I didn't write all of this code. I've been tasked to learn how to add this little feature in as an introduction to programming as a whole.

**Edit: Can anybody show me a fix for this? Like I say I'm very new to this and I don't fully understand everything yet.

Answer (score 1):

> They accept arbitrary inputs (called “props”) and return React elements describing what should appear on the screen. - see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

"props" is a channel to transport user's input into your component. e.g.

```
<DatePickerWidget startDate="2020/09/01" endDate="2020/09/30"/>
```

In your DatePickerWidget component, you can read the user's input "2020/09/01" by `this.props.startDate`.
If you'd like to read `this.props.update` as a function from your DatePickerWidget, then you need to input a function when you use it. Just like

```
<DatePickerWidget startDate="2020/09/01" endDate="2020/09/30"/ update=<your_update_handler>>
```

I guess you want to pass the SearchBox's `update` function to DatePickerWidget, so you could do this

```
<DatePickerWidget startDate="2020/09/01" endDate="2020/09/30"/ update=this.props.update>
```

Comment: Thanks! So this stops me from getting that error, I can type a date in however when I click the date picker to select the date, it doesn't update the date display. However I still don't get an error so its better than what I was doing!

Answer (score 0):

There is not function called update on the props object. Either you can define a function called update in the parent component of the components you want to use the this.props.update on. And then pass it down to the child components like so:

```
<SearchBox update={this.props.update}/>
```

But what you are probably looking for is to update the state of the SearchBox. state can be changed from within the component, whereas props cannot be changed directly, only by making a change in the parent component.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to ask a question like this, but I'm drawing a blank... how would I define that function?

Comment: Just like any function of a javascript class. and then you pass it to the children components. Whenever the children components then call the function, it is activated in the parent component. (and you can for example change the state of the parent component, to have a single source of truth for all children.)

Answer (score 0):

In SearchBar

```
import React from "react";

import { TextField, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

import "./SearchBox.css"
import DatePickerWidget from "./DatePickerWidget"

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { searchTerm: "", results: "" };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.validateSearch = this.validateSearch.bind(this);
    this.clear = this.clear.bind(this);

  
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: this.props.searchTerm });
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.searchTerm !== this.props.searchTerm)
      this.setState({ searchTerm: this.props.searchTerm });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.update({ searchTerm: this.state.searchTerm });
    this.setState({ results: this.state.searchTerm });
  }

  validateSearch() {
    return this.state.searchTerm !== "";
  }

  clear() {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: "", results: "" });
    this.props.update({ searchTerm: "" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form id="search-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Button
            style={{ width: "40%" }}
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary"
            onClick={this.clear}
            disabled={this.state.results === ""}
          >
            Clear
          </Button>
          <TextField
            style={{ flexBasis: "100%" }}
            variant="outlined"
            label="Search Term"
            type="search"
            name="searchTerm"
            value={this.state.searchTerm}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <Button
            style={{ width: "40%" }}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            disabled={!this.validateSearch()}
            type="submit"
          >
            Search
          </Button>


          <DatePickerWidget startDate="2020/09/01" endDate="2020/09/30" update={() => console.log('props passed')}/>
        </form>

        
        {this.state.results && (
          <Typography align="center" variant="body1">
            Displaying results for: {this.state.results}
          </Typography>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}


export default SearchBox;
```

And In Your date picker

```
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

class DatePickerWidget extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Paper id="date-picker-widget" elevation={8}>
        <Paper id="date-filters" elevation={8}>
          <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              margin="normal"
              id="date-picker-dialog"
              label="Start Date"
              format="yyyy/MM/dd"
              value={this.props.startDate}
              maxDate={this.props.endDate}
              onChange={(date) => this.props.update({ startDate: date })}
              KeyboardButtonProps={{
                "aria-label": "change start date",
              }}
            />
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              margin="normal"
              id="date-picker-dialog"
              label="End Date"
              format="yyyy/MM/dd"
              value={this.props.endDate}
              minDate={this.props.startDate}
              onChange={ this.props.update}
              KeyboardButtonProps={{
                "aria-label": "change end date",
              }}
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        </Paper>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

export default DatePickerWidget;
```

This all was caused because you never passed any props to your DatePicker from parent

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not entirely sure _how_ to do that. Sorry, very fresh to this world!

Comment: Write the update function and pass it to datePicker as a prop. And you are done.Don't forget to like the answer, if it helped in someway

Comment: OK, thanks again! It's more of I don't know actually _what_ to write... I'm stuck in 'tutorial hell' at the minute so I'm staring at the screen drawing a blank...